# How to create a checkbox/options button and change its values in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I create an `OptionButton` with

```
For Each c In Selection
    Dim right As Range
    Set right = c.Offset(0, 1)
    Button = ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width, c.Height)
    With Button
        .LinkedCell = right.Address   ' has no effect
        .Characters.Text = ""
        .Name = right.Address
    End With
Next
```

I want to change the `LinkedCell` of the newly created button, but the `With` block doesn't have an effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a control, the function returns an Object which has to be `Set` to a variable.

Try: `Set Button = ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width, c.Height)`